# I can't delete a project in my eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Neon eclipse on Windows 10. I've deleted my old project and it still seems to pop up after I delete it from my workshop. I don't know how it just keeps reviving itself after I delete literally everything inside that project folder.

Any advice?

EDIT: Eclipse 4.6.0 Neon. I want to be specific.

Comment: What are you doing to delete the project?  The proper way is to right-click on the project name in the Project Explorer or Package Explorer and select "Delete", and then check the "Delete project contents" checkbox.

Comment: It works now..Thank you for your help David M. Karr. I didn't know this was the 'right' way.

Answer (score 2):

(Just for the record.)

The proper way to delete a project is to right-click on the project name in the "Package Explorer" or "Project Explorer", select "Delete" and check the "Delete project contents" checkbox, then click OK.